# Android Unity plugin

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, unity-game-engine

I want to use unity android plugin in my AR application. The app has an AR camera, an image target and a 3d object.

**ON ECLIPSE :**

I create a default android application on eclipse. I click build automatically and check `project name -> proeprties -> isLibrary`. I create a class named **Bridge** on eclipse project.

**Bridge.java**

```
package com.tutorial.pluginforunity;
public class Bridge {

    public static int ReturnInt() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

**ON UNITY :**
I create a `BridgeForUnity.cs` file. Conent of it :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class BridgeForAndroid : MonoBehaviour {

    #if UNITY_ANDROID 
    //&& !UNITY_EDITOR
    public static int ReturnInt () {
        AndroidJavaClass ajc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.tutorial.pluginforunity.Bridge");
        return ajc.CallStatic<int>("ReturnInt") ;
    }
    #endif

    void Start () {

    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

I edit `DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs` that attached to image target.

```
private void Update() {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID 
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Return = " + BridgeForAndroid.ReturnInt());
    #endif
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) { Application.Quit(); }
}
```

I copy jar file under bin folder in eclipse project. I paste it under Assets/Plugins/Android.When I run this application, I see only black screen.

Comment: Have you tried moving this code from `Update` to `OnGUI`?

Comment: I run this application by toggle line commend this line `GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Return = " + BridgeForAndroid.ReturnInt());`. I see  black screen when it runs.

Comment: Yes, you already said this in the question. Still, have you tried moving this code to `OnGUI` method?

Comment: Sorry :) I tried it, I see `Return = 5`. Plugin works succesfully. I cannot see live camera view.

Comment: Yes, because nothing in the code you posted suggests that you should see a live camera view.

Comment: If you add to scene an AR camera without any code, you can see live camera view. I build&run my app, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the return value from a plugin, move the code to `OnGUI` from `Update`.